# python requests - scrape https://imgur.com

Tags: python, python-requests, imgur

i am trying to get the photos content (bytes) from https://imgur.com using:

```
from requests import get

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

divs = soup(get('https://imgur.com/a/...').text,'html.parser').find('div',{'class':'post-image-container'})
```

but the request i send gives me this page [image]

i mean is it the end of the road if i found a website that blocks requests ?

(i don't want to use Selenium)

[image]

Comment: Have you considered tweaking the `User-Agent`?

Comment: i did , did not work

Comment: also used the cfuid from my browser and it also did not work

Comment: I didn't find a class called `post-image-container`.

Comment: i will add it with the post

Answer (score 0):

**Hey , ☑️ Use Rotating proxies to avoid 404:**

---

**Step 1:**
(I have used free proxy here)

```
pip3 install bs4 requests stem
```

Automatically grab this list of free available proxies:

```
import requests
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_free_proxies():
    url = "https://free-proxy-list.net/"
    # get the HTTP response and construct soup object
    soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    proxies = []
    for row in soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "proxylisttable"}).find_all("tr")[1:]:
        tds = row.find_all("td")
        try:
            ip = tds[0].text.strip()
            port = tds[1].text.strip()
            host = f"{ip}:{port}"
            proxies.append(host)
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return proxies
```

**Step 2 :**

If you wants to check first 10 proxies:

```
get_free_proxies()[:10]

>> Output : ['45.235.216.112:8080',
 '139.255.11.148:8080',
 '139.255.11.146:8080',
 '152.67.24.187:80',
 '197.220.109.222:80',
 '180.250.12.10:80',
 '87.140.8.148:8080',
 '14.207.60.6:3128',
 '136.243.254.196:80',
 '52.56.100.107:3128']

proxies = ['45.235.216.112:8080',
 '139.255.11.148:8080',
 '139.255.11.146:8080',
 '152.67.24.187:80',
 '197.220.109.222:80',
 '180.250.12.10:80',
 '87.140.8.148:8080',
 '14.207.60.6:3128',
 '136.243.254.196:80',
 '52.56.100.107:3128']
```

**Step 3 :**

Create Session

```
def get_session(proxies):
    # construct an HTTP session
    session = requests.Session()
    # choose one random proxy
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    session.proxies = {"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
    return session
```

**Step 4 :**

```
for i in range(5):
    s = get_session(proxies)
    try:
        print("Request page with IP:", s.get("https://imgur.com/", timeout=1.5).text.strip())
        divs = soup(get('https://imgur.com/').text,'html.parser').find('div',{'class':'post-image-container'})
        print(divs)
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

✅  Here is the output :

```
Request page with IP: <!doctype html> <html lang=en> <head> <meta charset=utf-8> <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> <meta name=keywords content="funny, image, gif, gifs, memes, jokes, image upload, upload image, lol, humor, vote, comment, share, imgur, imgur.com, wallpaper"/> <meta name=description content="Discover the magic of the internet at Imgur, a community powered entertainment destination. Lift your spirits with funny jokes, trending memes, entertaining gifs, inspiring stories, viral videos, and so much more."/> ....
```

Comment: i can not make a `request.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')` because my country dose not allow it.

Comment: and when i used ur proxies it all gave me "Not supported proxy scheme None"

Comment: Then you can use a VPN or rotating proxies according to your region if you want to execute it!